# Homebrew replaced Python3, how to reverse?

Tags: linux, debian, homebrew

While trying to install AWS SAM CLI on a linux box, I had to install Homebrew/Linuxbrew. The AWS package have a dependency to python 3, which I already have installed on my system.
In the middle of the homebrew installation logs, I see this:

```bsh
==> Pouring python-3.7.4.x86_64_linux.bottle.tar.gz
==> /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python/3.7.4/bin/python3 -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install --force --verbose --install-scripts=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python/3.7.4
==> /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python/3.7.4/bin/python3 -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install --force --verbose --install-scripts=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python/3.7.4
==> /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python/3.7.4/bin/python3 -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install --force --verbose --install-scripts=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python/3.7.4
==> Caveats
Python has been installed as
  /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/python3

Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
`python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been installed into
  /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/python/libexec/bin
```

Following which:

```bsh
$ which python3
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/python3
```

This does *not* sit well with me, as it didn't warned before, left me no choice, and I trust my distribution a lot more than homebrew.

My first thought was to remove the package:

```bsh
$ brew uninstall python3
Error: Refusing to uninstall /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python/3.7.4
because it is required by aws-sam-cli, which is currently installed.
You can override this and force removal with:
  brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python3
```

Which mean I can't simply remove it

Now, having a dependency installed is bearable, but not if it replace my system native package, so my question is:

Is there a way to tell homebrew to *not* mess up with my system in the future, and to get back my native python ?

Comment: The native `python3` executable would be used if its directory is before `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin` in your `$PATH`. Net turning this into an answer because I don't know the answer to you actual question at the end (and I don't really know what you mean by "messing with my system").

Comment: By "messing with", I mean trying to replace native packages, like it did with `python3`. Moving brew in the `PATH` could be a solution, I think I ll remove it entirely from the `PATH` so that it become a non issue

Comment: Brew never replaced anything. It is _very carefully_ keeping it's software separate from your base system.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling aws-sam-cli, homebrew's python, and then hombrew itself. and then using the debian packaged version of pip to install it - `pip3 install aws-sam-cli`?   Or even examining the aws-sam-cli code to find out what lib modules it needs, installing the debian packages for them (if they exist), and then installing aws-sam-cli from the github repo?   Vendor install instructions should always be viewed with suspicion because they care about their app, not your system....such instructions are often some awful brute force method that makes no effort to integrate with the system

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linuxbrew will install packages that provide dependencies to packages that you install, as needed.  Sometimes these dependencies (or for that matter, packages that you install with `brew`) will provide the same services or tools as software already present on your system.  Linuxbrew will not *replace* software already installed by other means on your system, since what it installs is installed in a totally separate location (by design).

To make sure that commands provided by `brew` does not take precedence over commands installed in other ways, make sure that the various Linuxbrew `bin` directories are last in your `$PATH`, or at least *after* the `bin` directories holding your "native" commands on your system.

I believe that Linuxbrew adds the following to a user's `~/.bash_profile` (or asks the user to add it, I don't remember):

```bash
eval $(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

(or something similar).

This causes the command

```
export PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:$PATH"
```

to be executed, which adds the Linuxbrew paths to the *front* of your `$PATH`.

You can run the `brew shellenv` command in your terminal and copy its output into your `~/.bash_profile` file (there should be a number of `export` statements), replacing the corresponding call there completely, and *changing* the `export PATH` command into

```sh
export PATH="$PATH:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin"
```

This makes sure that commands in your default (non-Linuxbrew) `$PATH` have precedence over the `brew` commands.  If this breaks any `brew` packages that depend on the Linuxbrew version of commands or not, I cannot say.

Comment: Couldn't connect over the week end to validate, but had the time to cool of and take a fresh look, that was exactly the problem.
For my use, the commands do not break, so that's fine

Comment: Or, instead of copying and pasting the output, you can add something like this to your init file: `oldPATH=PATH; eval $(...) ; export PATH=$oldPATH:/home/linuxbrew/...`. That way, if `brew shellenv` gets updated later, you won't need to port that update to your init file.

Comment: You can also do `brew unlink python3`